# getCheckedRadioButtonId() returns -1 even after the radio button is checked

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to get text from selected radiobutton. this code was working fine yesterday but now it's returning null and I don't understand why or what's suddenly causing it.

Renaming variable, rewriting the code, re define variable, re initializing it does nothing to solve this.

**the XML**

```
      <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupMurid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtKelaminMurid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Jenis Kelamin"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMuridLaki"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Laki-Laki" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioMuridPerempuan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Perempuan" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

**Activity**

```
private RadioGroup radioGroup;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);

setContentView(R.layout.murid_detail_activity);

radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupMurid);

getRadioChecked();

}

public void getRadioChecked(){
    int sexMurid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    RadioButton rbSelected = (RadioButton) findViewById(sexMurid);
    jenisKelamin = rbSelected.getText().toString();
}
```

This is really fine yesterday, I just don't know what's causing it? can anyone help?

Comment: Please help, I'm already out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when **RadioButton** is not a **direct child** of **RadioGroup**. In your code the direct child of RadioGroup is LinearLayout. Try with the RadioGroup tag inside of LinearLayout like this:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtKelaminMurid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Jenis Kelamin"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupMurid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMuridLaki"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Laki-Laki" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMuridPerempuan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Perempuan" />
        
    </RadioGroup>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` (as in the docs) is an `int`. An `int` cannot be `null`, so I think you should rely on `-1`.

Edit: If you're not sure how an Android component works, just check the source code :) For the `RadioGroup`, see for example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/RadioGroup.java#RadioGroup.clearCheck%28%29

Comment: yes, but -1 means none of the radiobuttons in the radiogroup is checked right? but I clearly checked the radiobutton, even defaulted 1 button to be checked using `android:checked = "true"`. beside as you can see in the code I want to get the text of Checked radiobutton

Comment: Try this: 
 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,
                    rbSelected.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupMurid);
    RadioButton rbSelected = (RadioButton) findViewById(sexMurid);
    RadioButton radioMuridPerempuan = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioMuridPerempuan);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.sexMurid) {
                jenisKelamin = rbSelected.getText().toString();
            else if (checkedId == R.id.radioMuridPerempuan) {
                jenisKelamin = radioMuridPerempuan.getText().toString();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, I have tried this too and it is still the same. I have identified the problem lies with radiobuttons, however I don't know why my Radio buttons could ben checked both at the same time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).